# Meteor : How to get iron-router parameter in template

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, iron-router

How to get get route param values in template?

**Router**

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('userpost', {path: '/mypost/:_id'});
  this.route('usercomment', {path: '/mycomments/:_id'});
});
```

my current location is `localhost:3000/mypost/12345`. I want to assign a path parameter from a route param

**Template**

```
<template name="mytemplate">
    <a class="tab-item" href="{{pathFor 'userpost' _id=???}}">Post</a>
    <a class="tab-item" href="{{pathFor 'usercomment' _id=???}}">Comment</a>
</template>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{{pathFor}}` is using the current data context to replace URL parameters with actual values, so you need to enclose the call inside a `{{#with}}` block helper.

```
<template name="mytemplate">
  {{#with context}}
    <a class="tab-item" href="{{pathFor "userpost"}}">Post</a>
    <a class="tab-item" href="{{pathFor "usercomment"}}">Comment</a>
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

`context` is a helper returning an object that have an `_id`, and this property will be used to fill-in the computed path.

```
Template.mytemplate.helpers({
  context: function(){
    return {
      _id: Router.current().params._id
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: please checkout my edited question. both `a` tags are in same template

Comment: Why is this a problem ? Just make sure `post` and `comment` are helpers defined on this template ?

Comment: I doesn't know whether its good practice to create helper for every `a` tags?

Comment: I can't see any major problem with that.

Comment: Could you PLEASE add code for helpers with computed path?

Comment: Edited my answer, maybe that's closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Typeo {{/width}} should be {{/with}}